# DNN and PayPal, how to sent email to customer after payment has been made

Tags: paypal, dotnetnuke

In my DNN website, using Paypal's Checkout button, when user has click the buy button and sent to Paypal. Make a payment and then redirect back to my site.

Question: 
How can I get that customer email address (from Paypal) so that i can sent a conformation email to him/her from my DNN website?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways; you can either call the GetTransactionDetails API and supply the TRANSACTIONID as a parameter. 'EMAIL' will contain the buyer's (PayPal) email address. 
Or you can use PayPal IPN to get notified through POST whenever a payment / action has been made.

GetTransactionDetails API doc is at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails
You can also have a look at TransactionSearch for past transactions.

In case you want to use IPN, just supply NOTIFYURL in your SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment call if you're using Express Checkout, or  if you're using Website Payments Standard. 
Remember to send the POST back to PayPal for validation at paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate and check for a VERIFIED / INVALID response.
Some sample code and docs for IPN is available at https://www.paypal.com/ipn/